# How to use batch file to compare and get uuid

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I recently took interest in batch file coding and now i have a project i am working on.
in the project, i have created a basic program that require users to input their Licence code which i have stored in a text file(about 50 lines of licenses) and embeded it in my batch file with a third pary application that convert my batch file to .exe(about 50 lines of licenses). i have about 42 computers in my organization branch where i want to deploy the program.

My challenge however is that since the batch file and the Licence file are all in one .exe, One key would work on all 42 computers. which is very bad.

i have tried using wmic csproduct get uuid to compare computers but i just could not find my way.

Please i really need help with this.

here are my work so far:

```
SETLOCAL
:startup
SET "Password_File=%UserProfile%\Desktop\Password_File.txt"
set "fail="
set "Activation_Code="
set /p "Activation_Code=Your Activation Code Here: "
REM cls
IF NOT DEFINED Activation_Code ( GOTO :startup

 )

findstr /X /l /c:"%Activation_Code%" <"%Password_File%" >nul || set fail=1
if defined fail (
echo Invalid Activation Code!
"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Msgbox Failed.vbs"
    GOTO :startup
)


:yes

REM cls

echo Success, you have access!
REm >> %Password_File% echo %Activation_Code%
    "%UserProfile%\Desktop\MsgboxSuccess.vbs"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe"

:: This line remove the already entered activation code from the licence file copied to the computer


type %Password_File% | find /V "%Activation_Code%" >XXFile.txt
del "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Password_File.txt" 
ren %UserProfile%\Desktop\XXFile.txt Password_File.txt

goto :eof


:nope
REM cls
echo Activation Code has already been used or Invalid!
"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Msgbox Failed.vbs"
:: ping locahost -n 3 >nul

GOTO :startup
```

i want my batch file to log the following to a destkop file
where LOG_FILE = %Userprofile%\Desktop\LogFolder\LOG_FILE.txt

```
wmic csproduct get name >>%LOG_FILE%
wmic csproduct get UUID>>%LOG_FILE%
```

then compare the UUID log in %LOG_FILE is the same as the current computer's UUID
if so then it should verify the same for the Computer name.

the whole idea

```
@echo off

if wmic csproduct get UUID == "DAC2D186-1AB9-E111-A120-B888E34233CEE" (echo Done! ) else (  echo Not Done!) pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The future as stated by Microsoft is PowerShell and CIM. I have not yet found a CIM class that includes UUID, but this will work.

```
FOR /F %%u IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID"') DO (SET "UUID=%%u")
ECHO UUID is set to %UUID%
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `for /f` loop to get the output of a command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic csproduct get UUID^, name /format:list ^|find "="') do set "%%a"
echo "%uuid%"
echo "%name%"
```